# How to handle in place text editing in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, text, runtime, edit, at-command

I have a program that dynamically draws rectangles and then draws the string (name and description) inside the rectangles. My intended behavior is when a user clicks on any of the rectangle, it should show the typing cursor and allow the text to be edited.

What I have tried so far is create a textbox overlay the rectangle the user clicked on. This seems to work ok but I feel as if this isn't the best way to handle it. Does anyone have an alternate solution/idea?

Comment: I feel like that is the best way to handle it. Otherwise, you're reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

its a bit complicated and maybe not worth it but,
you can listen to user keyboard and when is clicking the rectangle start inputting the text from keyboard to a label (on top of the rectangle)...